# string match with float phrase

Tags: php, regex

There is a string with server's dynamic uptime output
e.g.:

```
20:17:49 up 3 days, 9:25, 1 user, load average: 1.19, 1.34, 1.36
22:00:12 up 1 min, load average: 1.39, 0.46, 0.16
06:40:39 up 445 days, 1:08,  3 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.01, 0.00
```

where *", 1 user"* phrase may or may not exist.
I need to get only uptime part of this string viz.: "*3 days, 9:25*"

What is the shortest variant to do this using php or/and regex?

**EDIT:** sorry, forgot to mention that string consist of dynamic content

Comment: The only part you _ever_ need is `3 days, 9:25`?

Comment: yes but this part is dynamic, it also can be "6:12" without days

Comment: @user947668 That bit of information would change the regex quite a bit. You should consider updating the question with this information and maybe a couple use cases for people to test.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this might be easy with a regular expression (if you know regular expressions), I'd say this is done best on ones own to learn about PHP the following:

1. Find the first position of `' up '` (see [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos)).
2. Find from that position the next position of `', '`.
3. Find from that position the next position of `', '` (again).
4. From the position of 1. and the length of the search-string in 1. with a length until the position found out in 3., get the [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) of the string in question.

You have your result then. I leave this as an excercise to write the concrete code. Let me know if you've got any issue writing it.

---

just seeing your comment, you're unsure if there are actually two commas. You would then need to look for the commas from behind maybe.

---

At some level then a regular expression comes hand then because it can pretty precisely formulate the matching conditions and can make certain parts optional:

```
$pattern = '/(?<= up )(?:\d+ days?, )?\d{1,2}:\d\d/';
$uptime  = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $m) ? $m[0] : FALSE;
```

This is a lookbehind like searching for the first position of `' up '` in the pure PHP outline above (that is why it's good to write things first with PHP string function, it's good to learn and get an idea how a regular expression could be build then), then it's looking for the days pattern which is optional. Here regex is pretty powerful because it is easy to express looking for numbers. Then finally looking for the digits of time.

Perhaps this still needs some modification, I'm not entirely sure of the uptime pattern for the hours/minutes part. What if it is one day and one minute for example? Or just one day, 0 minutes? What will happen then?

Comment: hakre, thank you for extended answer. unfortunately your pattern will fail in several cases. anyway i found another way how to solve my problem, but solution is not related to php/regex parsing.

Comment: @user947668: That is the part I was noting about at the very end. The pattern must be written so that it fits for the output. As you have not specified the output well, I could not suggest a more specific one. But apart from that, the key point is to learn how to create these patterns, not if one question here contains the exact one you need (at least not with such an unsepcific question). If this follows some standard, name that standard, outline it, make the question concrete *but* also generic so that it's useful for many. Than a regex answer can be a good reference here on site.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$string = '20:17:49 up 3 days, 9:25, 1 user, load average: 1.19, 1.34, 1.36';
$result = substr($string, strpos($string, 'up')+3, strpos($string, ',') - strpos($string, 'up')+3);
```

See http://codepad.viper-7.com/gDG4Lf

Comment: Could be dangerous because the numbers of days could be larger than 1 digit...

Comment: @devOp No, because I cut off the (mistakenly assumed static part of the) beginning. When the numbers of digits of the days increase, the value of `strpos()` increases too, because the `,` shifts one to the right :) However, you are "a kind of right", because the uptime may exceed 24h. I'll have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Since you *asked* for a RegEx:

```
$regEx = '/.+? up (?:([1-9]+ days, ))?([1]?\d{1}:[0-5]\d{1}).*+/';

// With days included:
$str = '20:17:49 up 3 days, 9:25, 1 user, load average: 1.19, 1.34, 1.36';
echo preg_replace($regEx, "$1$2", $str);

    3 days, 9:25

// No days included:
$str = '20:17:49 up 9:25, 1 user, load average: 1.19, 1.34, 1.36';
echo preg_replace($regEx, "$1$2", $str);

    9:25
```

The RegEx could be more compact, but not much without making it too lenient.  There's one small problem with this (at least) - it will allow for a time that starts with `0:`, but I've spent too much time on this already, heh.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it without regex, just using the `explode()` command:

```
$str = "20:17:49 up 3 days, 9:25, 1 user, load average: 1.19, 1.34, 1.36";
$array = explode(" ", $str);
echo $array[2] . " " . $array[3] . " " . $array[4];
```

Edit: Correction of echo result.

Comment: Which will output: `up3days`

Comment: Won't let me un-downvote you unless you edit it, sorry.